# Typescript workflow using GNU Make

Tags: gnu-make

I cobbled together a very light-weight process of bundling JS files built from Typescript. TLDR: I run `tsc` to generate `js/foo.js` for every `src/foo.ts`. Then I bundle the JS files using `esbuild`. Here's the rough dependency graph:

```
pkg/         js/                             src/
  a.js   ->    a.js   -.               .->     a.ts
  b.js   ->    b.js   --> .compiled   -+->     b.ts
  c.js   ->    c.js   -'               '->     c.ts
```

Because `tsc`, like Java, compiles the whole code base at once, unconditionally, rather than individual source files, I've used a `.compiled` file as an intermediate proxy to indicate `tsc` compilation.

And here's the watered-down but standalone, functional, Makefile (slightly edited since original post):

```
.PHONY: bundle
bundle: .bundled

src_stems := a b c
ts_files := $(addsuffix .ts,$(addprefix src/,$(src_stems)))
js_files := $(addsuffix .js,$(addprefix js/,$(src_stems)))
pkg_files := $(addsuffix .js,$(addprefix pkg/,$(src_stems)))

.bundled: $(pkg_files)
    touch $@

pkg:
    mkdir -p $@

pkg/%.js: js/%.js | pkg
    cp $< $@

$(js_files): .compiled

# Simulate running tsc
.compiled: $(ts_files)
    mkdir -p js
    touch $(js_files)
    touch $@

.PHONY:
clean:
    rm -rf pkg js .compiled .bundled
```

Everything works as expected upon `make clean bundle`.

```bash
$ mkdir -p src
$ touch src/{a,b,c}.ts
$ make
```

However, I'm surprised at the behaviour when bundling after single file update. For example, running this after a clean build:

```
$ touch src/b.ts # I modify a single source
$ make
mkdir -p js
touch js/a.js js/b.js js/c.js
touch .compiled
cp js/b.js pkg/b.js    <- Note a.js isn't being bundled!
cp js/c.js pkg/c.js
touch .bundled
```

And, if I run `make` again, the missing file is caught up:

```
$ make
cp js/a.js pkg/a.js
touch .bundled
```

I tried debugging with `make -d` but can't figure out why, when I have partial updates, it takes two runs to get `a.js` bundled. Note also that it's always `a.js` that's missed out, which I suppose is because it's the first source to be listed.

Some debug lines from `make -d`:

```
     Prerequisite 'js/a.js' is older than target 'pkg/a.js'.
...
     Prerequisite 'js/b.js' is newer than target 'pkg/b.js'.
...
     Prerequisite 'js/c.js' is newer than target 'pkg/c.js'.
```

The diagnostic for `pkg/a.js` line is at odds with the rest. In fact, all the `js/*.js` files will have the same timestamp.

What am I doing wrong? Are there other set of rules I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
js/a.js js/b.js js/c.js: .compiled
```

is not sufficient.  It tells make there's a prerequisite, but it doesn't provide any recipe.  You want to have a recipe so that it's a full rule, not just a prerequisite declaration.  Adding a semicolon would be enough (I believe):

```
js/a.js js/b.js js/c.js: .compiled ;
```

alternatively you could add something like this if that's more understandable:

```
js/a.js js/b.js js/c.js: .compiled
        # do nothing
```

Just a note: it would be simpler to read your example (and realize it's correct) if you assigned the source files to a variable and used that variable, instead of rewriting all the files every time, where we have to carefully parse them to be sure they're not mistyped.

Comment: Thanks - looks like I was missing the semi-colon, as you suggested. I've been using make for a long time, and this nuance never occurred to me, nor have I come across the concept of 'prerequisite declaration' (if it's a thing). From what I can find about [empty recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Empty-Recipes.html), I wonder if some implicit rules were kicking in, when the semicolon wasn't present.

I've also edited the example to introduce variables for easier reading.

Comment: No.  You can easily see that there is no possible builtin rule that will match those targets, by running `make -p` and examining them.  The issue is the next paragraph AFTER the one discussing implicit rules.

Comment: An except from `make -p` is pasted above in the original question. The reason cited for not updating is that the prerequisite is older for `a.js`, whereas it's newer for all other files.

Comment: That is an excerpt from `make -d`.  I suggested you run `make -p` (that prints the rules database so you can see there are no rules that will match these targets in the built-in database of rules, so it cannot be that _some implicit rules were kicking in_.

Comment: Yeah, it was `make -d` -- my bad. From what I can see, both with and without the suggested semicolon, there are no differences in printed rules from `make -p`. After all, without the semicolon, both `b.js` and `c.js` were created; since their rules arise out of the same implicit rule, I don't get why only `a.js` wasn't. One difference I noticed was `# Implicit rule search has been done.` (without semicolon) vs. `# Implicit rule search has not been done.` (with semicolon). By the way, the makefile is self-contained and standalone; the test case is locally-reproducible.

Comment: The _only_ thing I was pointing out with `-p` is that your idea that _some implicit rules were kicking in_ is not correct, since you can see from the output of `-p` that there are no implicit rules that could match.  That's all.  Nothing else.  Yes, since you didn't have an explicit rule, make would do an implicit rule search,  But that would not find anything since there are no implicit rules that match.  The paragraph on empty recipes starting _Empty recipes can also be used ..._ is the docs you are looking for.  This has nothing to do with implicit rules.